# List of inactive accounts has empty logon dates

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to run a script to capture accounts that haven't logged in for 90 days or greater.  I need the script to exclude certain EmployeeIDs that are service accounts in our environment.  I have the following script that works, but the `LastLogonDate` is blank in the output.  Is there a way to keep my filters while being able to capture the `LastLogonDate` field in the output?

```
$Users = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 |
         FT SamAccountName

$(Foreach ($user in $Users) { 
    Get-ADUser -Filter {
        -not ( lastlogontimestamp -like "*") -and
        (enabled -eq $true) -and 
        (EmployeeID -ne "Project Mailbox") -and 
        (EmployeeID -ne "Resource") -and 
        (EmployeeID -ne "Contractor")
    } -Properties SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, EmployeeID, physicalDeliveryOfficeName
}) | FT SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, EmployeeID, physicalDeliveryOfficeName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty `LastLogonDate` property means that the account has never been logged on. You get only these accounts, because you restrict your results to them with the filter clause `-not (lastlogontimestamp -like "*")`, which translates to "accounts whose `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute does not have a value".

With that said, your approach is more complicated than it has to be. `Format-*` cmdlets should only ever be used for presenting data to users. For selecting data during processing use `Select-Object` (with the `-Expand` parameter if you need the values of a particular property). You don't need to filter here, though, because the output of `Search-ADAccount` can be fed directly into `Get-ADUser`.

You probably want something like this:

```psh
$excludeList = 'Project Mailbox','Resource','Contractor'
$properties  = 'SamAccountName', 'LastLogonDate', 'EmployeeID',
               'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'

Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 |
  Get-ADUser -Properties $properties |
  ? { $_.Enabled -and $excludeList -notcontains $_.EmployeeID } |
  Format-Table $properties
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and your help cleaning up my inefficient scripts.  I was pretty certain there was a better way, but I didn't know what that was.

If I wanted to run the same script but for disabled accounts, how would I change the $_.Enabled to capture the disabled accounts?

Comment: @KSpinnato Simply negate the clause (`-not $_.Enabled`).

Comment: thanks for the update.  Sorry for the late reply, I was dealing with mass flooding in my area and have been out of pocket.  Thanks!